# Get background color of a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, colors

I need to change the background color of a listview many times, but I don't know how to obtain the color that the listview has before clicking on it.

I have this code:

```
if(colores.get(i).equals("0"))
                {
                    listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else if(colores.get(i).equals("1"))
                {
                    listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(colores.get(i).equals("2"))
                {
                    listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                }
                else
                {
                    listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
```

And I can change the color, but I need also to change the color when I click on one item of the listview, but I don't know how to know the color that it has previously.

Can anyone help me? Thanks! :)

Comment: you want to change the color of item while selection inside listview ? and is it fix color that you want to display on selection ?

Comment: you can also handle in listview adapter, it would be easier

Comment: what do you have in each listview item? is it just strings?

Comment: I have strings, and the strings don't change the text when I make click on it, this is OK.

Comment: I need to change the color depending on the color it has before, for example, if it is red, then it has to be blue.

Answer (score 0):

Do this: change the color then create a handler. Also, make View view to final View view. You can do if/else statement or switch statement based on what child it is or in other words the position of the item.

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); //on click change to red

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); //after click changes to white
                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 200); //change to white after 200ms
        }
    });

    //DO THIS BELOW FOR SPECIFIC ITEM IN LISTVIEW

private final String currentColor_P1; //current background color for item at position 1

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 1) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else if (position == 2) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

            //OR check for position and check for the known color that you have set for that position
            if(position == 1 && currentColor_P1 == BLUE) {
                 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

            } else if(position == 1 && currentColor_P1 == RED) {
                 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }

            //Change color to whatever after clicked and after initial color change happened
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                    //or 
                    if(position == 1){
                         view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
                         currentColor_P1 = "BLUE"; //now you set the current backgound for item at position 1 to "blue"
                    }



                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 200);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I need for example, if the color was red, when I make click the color change to blue. I mean, I need to change the color depending on the color that it has before. With this example I think I change the color depending on the position of the item clicked not on the color it has before, isn't it?

Comment: Well, you can define variables for each color depending on the position. So when you click on an item in listview, the code checks for the defined colors of each item in listview. If the item clicked is RED, then you create a switch statement by changing the color from RED to let's say WHITE.

Comment: You can also define a private variable called currentColor either for each position or by itself. This way every time you click on at item or change its color, just make sure to change the currentColor variable also. So that way on your onClick statement, you just for the currentColor, and then change it to another based on that.

Comment: Your listView will usually contain the same color for each item,unless you change the color on item click. However, after you click, you can change the color to anything, and retain the information about the color of that item after the on click item. So in my example, if you keep track of the position and current color of the item at a specific position then you can easily know what background color each item has. Or you can create a list of objects to pass to the Listview Adapter. These objects would contain the background color info for each item. Then you can use the object in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I try before post the question with the first of your answers, and it works, but I was looking for a better solution thinking that it could be implemented on the API. Thanks a lot, JamesLo! :)

Comment: I am glad it worked for you! The API for the listview is not that great. You end up having to create manual solutions for something that should have been in the api.